# Determining where parameters passed from view to controller originated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my `ApplicationController` parent class I have an action method called `dig` which reads parameters via the `params[]` hash-like structure.  I would like to have any view that builds a link to any controller via `link_to` helper function with the `dig` action to call the parent's action first.  I'd like to then be able to determine either what that parameterized information represents (its type), or what created the link (the previous or originating view).

Any ideas on the best way to do this?  Is there a way to pass an object via the `link_to` and then use its meta data?  If so, would this break the rails paradigm?

Comment: You seem a little fuzzy on `link_to`, so maybe this will help. Views don't "call" controllers. Your routes are defined in a way that they work both ways – building a URL, and determining the action from the URL. When you use `link_to`, it builds a URL/path from your routes.

Comment: Thanks for you comment coreyward.  I understand what you're explaining, and my question does tip my hand a bit in terms of how new I am with this.  From your comment it sounds as though object passing in this way is not possible.  Is there any way to determine what the previous view was that created that link?

Comment: Tried to clean the question up a bit using your recommendations.

Comment: You can pass that as an additional parameter or store that information in the session, or even just use the referrer. How you do it depends on how mission-critical it is that the information is accurate and what the architecture of your application is.

Comment: What would be the best way to pass this as an additional parameter?  Would I configure this in the routes?

Comment: @inyourcorner, can you include a code example of what you are needing to happen?

Comment: @robertwbradford, I'd like to specify the route such that I can pass into the url variable parameters, such as `my_url/:id_type1, :id_type2, :id_type3`.  Then, based on the type of parameter passed I can redirect the view to be given.  Similar to a hash of parameters into a method, where all are not required, and they are named so that I can determine where to redirect to based on which id_type was passed in.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for what called what inside your code, Ruby's [`caller`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Kernel#caller-instance_method) method is the basis for the stack dump that occurs when an exception occurs. You can tap into that and ask what the calling chain was at any point.

If you want to trace the incoming requests from the browser from an outside site, it becomes a lot more difficult because browsers don't like to reveal the last location any more. If the browser is being redirected around your own site you can use sessions or cookies to trace its movement.

Answer (score 1):

I think that to have the originating link what you would need to do is something like this:

```
request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
```

This will get the URL where the action was originated, from there you can process the URL to get controller, action and id. Hope this helps!